# Grails Tomcat Unable to serialize delta request for sessionid: groovy.lang.MapWithDefault

Tags: session, tomcat, grails, session-variables

The Grails Project that I am working on has the war deployed to mulitple Tomcats with Session Replication enabled.

We have made little changes recently related to sessions except for starting to use **useToken** in all g:form entities.  (There may be others, but an initial look at all the recent code submissions could not find anything related.)

I understand that the error below is related to session objects not being serializable, but I am not sure where to begin looking.

Does anyone have experience with the error below in Grails?

Could it be related to the useToken in the forms?

Is this a known limitation of useToken in g:forms - that they do not support serialization?

Alternately, how can I find all object in the session to see which one is causing this error?

```
 org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.requestCompleted Unable to serialize delta request for sessionid [6F6A26B3FF57A901F5D868FB68CA4A6F]
 java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.lang.MapWithDefault
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaRequest$AttributeInfo.writeExternal(DeltaRequest.java:384)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaRequest.writeExternal(DeltaRequest.java:277)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaRequest.serialize(DeltaRequest.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.serializeDeltaRequest(DeltaManager.java:617)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.requestCompleted(DeltaManager.java:1000)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.requestCompleted(DeltaManager.java:965)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.send(ReplicationValve.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.sendMessage(ReplicationValve.java:513)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.sendSessionReplicationMessage(ReplicationValve.java:495)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.sendReplicationMessage(ReplicationValve.java:406)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:329)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:  This is a known issue with Grails 2.2.1.

See https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9923

So essentially, if you are using Grails 2.2.1 with session replication enabled across the cluster, and are using Tokens, it will break session replication.